# Can Dapper handle nullable boolean/bit fields? [INVALID]

Tags: c#, sql-server, orm, dapper

I'm trying to use Dapper for the first time, but I've immediately run into the problem in that it doesn't seem that Dapper can handle nullable fields. This surprises me greatly as these are extremely common.

If I have a nullable boolean field in my SQL Server database and try and use Dapper to populate the nullable boolean property on my C# class, an exception is thrown if the boolean field contains a null value:

```
System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

Is there any fix or workaround for this?  I find it hard to believe Dapper can't handle this as it looks like it's been around for  a while and this is an extremely basic function.

**EDIT:  This was my mistake!  My column was actually a nvarchar which happened to contain 0 or 1, and as such, I hadn't noticed. Changing it to BIT (or the C# property to "string?") fixes the problem.**

Comment: Can you post your table definition and your Dapper code that's throwing the exception?

Comment: The fact that it mentions `string` tells me the problem could be your data/query... what is the column here?

Comment: The column is actually the result of a LEFT JOIN and shows as a DB null in SSIS. Perhaps this isn't recognised as as bool by Dapper?

Comment: @NickG well, perhaps it isn't actually a bool in the first place; what is the actual data here?

Comment: The original column is definitely a nullable bit (boolean) field. However in doing the LEFT JOIN, perhaps SQL Server converts it to something else?

Comment: @NickG I very much doubt that; however, you can use `ExecuteReader` to get the `IDataReader`, and check what type the column is via `reader.GetFieldType(ordinal)`.

Comment: Sorry my last comment was totally wrong!  Thanks @MarcGravell for the hint. While it had previously been working as a bit field when I wasn't using Dapper, it turns out the column was actually nvarchar :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yep, works just fine:

```
public void SO24607639_NullableBools()
{
    var obj = connection.Query<HazBools>(
        @"declare @vals table (A bit null, B bit null, C bit null);
        insert @vals (A,B,C) values (1,0,null);
        select * from @vals").Single();
    obj.IsNotNull();
    obj.A.Value.IsEqualTo(true);
    obj.B.Value.IsEqualTo(false);
    obj.C.IsNull();
}
class HazBools
{
    public bool? A { get; set; }
    public bool? B { get; set; }
    public bool? C { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: You're right. I'm an idiot. My column had been mapped to a NVARCHAR and I somehow hadn't noticed as my previous (non-dapper) code handled this OK somehow... I should perhaps delete this question?

Comment: @NickG entirely up to you

Comment: I'll leave it here in case anyone else makes the same stupid mistake :)

Answer (score 0):

Since Dapper does not make too much plumbing, the recordset coming from the database contains a string, a stated by the error. Try to check the column type, and when it is clear you can change the DTO class accordingly, or cast it in some way in the query.